# Git ignore files still listed in untracked list

Tags: git, gitignore

I try to ignore build files from VS, which are located on `obj` and `bin` catalogs.

In order to do that I specified (`.vs` is just catalog with some cached data, which is unnecesasry, I don't want that either):

```
**/.vs/**
.vs/
**/obj/**
obj/
**/bin/**
bin/
```

But even though, they still show in untracked files list and when I `git add` them, all these catalogs are added with all its content.

I know this has been talked about many times, but nothing seems to work for me.

I tried pushing `.gitignore` alone to make it take effect, but did not work.

I tried using slashes, forward slashes, double slashes, did not work.

I tried also following [this solution](http://shrestharohit.com.np/file-added-to-gitignore-still-showing-in-untracked-list/), did not work either...

I think I miss something really basic, but don't know what it might be.

Comment: Have these files already been committed?

Comment: "When I add them"?  Ignoring makes auto-add ignore them, not to stop you adding them explicitly.

Comment: Also: check that your ignore file isn't coded as utf-16.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, they have. But i remvoed them with `git rm`

Comment: @jthill Well, I don't add them explicitly. I wouldn't even expect them to show as untracked files.

Comment: @jthill Excellent guess with encoding - I had some really wild encoding (UCS-2 BE BOM - never heard of it untul now.. :D ) for some reason...

Comment: The same way unicode and git are the sweet spots despite real fan bases for all the competitors, utf-8 is the sweet spot for text encoding. Perceived (and a few real albeit minor or niche) advantages for all other encodings come with heavy downsides, and the simplicity advantage of converging on just one is huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was simple, but really unexpected (at least for me), so I want to leave the answer here to all people that are going to run into the same problem.
(also because I didn't find any clue pointing to that issue).

The thing that went wrong was encoding of a `.gitignore` file (it was UCS-2 BE BOM) - that caused GIT not to read it properly. As soon as I set it to `UTF-8` it worked.

Don't know what caused the encoding of a file, but it certainly disabled feature of `.gitignore` file.

And obviously, file itself can be simplified (I posted expanded version to show all my attempts) to this:

```
**/.vs/**
**/bin/**
**/obj/**
```